# Create multiple columns in R with multiple values created by a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using a function from a package. When I run the function, it creates 3 different values. Now, I want to run this function for several groups and add the generated values as the unique variable (column) in the original datasets. Is there way to deal with this?

I have written many codes that looks something like this:

```
df <- df %>%
      group_by(group_name) %>%
      mutate(new_var = function(var1, var2, var3)
```

I also tried:

```
df <- df %>%
      group_by(group_name) %>%
      mutate(list['a', 'b', 'c']= function(var1, var2, var3)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753108/add-multiple-columns-to-data-frame-using-a-function-that-returns-multiple-output

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).